# How to change exception priority on cortex-m4 processor in Rust?

Tags: rust, cortex-m, stm32f4discovery

I want to set interrupt priorities for processor internal exceptions. The `cortex_m` crate provides easy access to NVIC control registers. Specifically, there is a method that let me set priority for each interrupt.

```rust
let mut p = cortex_m::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
p.NVIC.set_priority(...);
```

`set_priority` asks me to pass an argument specifying for which interrupt I intend to modify the priority. Say I want to change the priority for `PendSV`. However, passing in `cortex_m::peripheral::scb::Exception::PendSV` will not work because it does not implement a required trait bound.

I am developing on STM32F407VGT6 board, so I also looked in the `stm32f4` crate, but I did not find any enum definition that can help either.

Should I write my own enum that implements the required trait so that it can specify interrupt numbers, or is there already some existing crate that can make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`InterruptNumber`](https://docs.rs/cortex-m/0.7.0/cortex_m/interrupt/trait.InterruptNumber.html), implementing this Trait is responsibility of the PAC (peripheral access crate) provider. Looking at the [`stm32f4`](https://docs.rs/stm32f4/0.12.1/stm32f4/index.html) crate, its latest release (`0.12.1` as of time of writing) is still dependant on `cortex-m >=0.5.8, <0.7`, meaning the developers likely haven't upgraded to the new API yet.

The old API makes use of the [`bare_metal::Nr`](https://docs.rs/bare-metal/0.2.5/bare_metal/trait.Nr.html) trait, which a few PACs stil rely on.

I found an example in the [cortex-m-quickstart](https://github.com/rust-embedded/cortex-m-quickstart/blob/master/examples/device.rs) guide that makes use of the old NVIC API.

I recommend you go by the dependency requirements of your PAC and downgrade to `cortex-m >=0.5.8, <0.7` and keep an eye out for updates to `stm32f4`.

Comment: I don't see definitions for processor generated interrupts in `stm32f4`. It currently only defines external interrupts. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct, I missed that. PendSV is an exception, and those are generic across all cortex-m devices. The ARM Cortex-M User Guide also states, that those exceptions, which have configurable priorities, can be controlled through the NVIC. It could simply be an oversight in the current API design. You could try to implement the Nr trait yourself.

Comment: You might also find this discussion of interest https://github.com/rust-embedded/cortex-m-rt/issues/44. While quite old, it states that exceptions are to be configured through the SCB API directly.